# How to handle multi-sensors data?

Tags: sensors, sensor-fusion

I am new to the sensor data fusion world. I want to find room vacancy using ultrasonic, PIR, and sound sensors.

These sensors deliver binary information about the occupancy. How can I combine the decision making from these three sensors? How can I calculate a good delay time for each sensor?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ..... it almost sounds like your question is not about sensors at all, but about binary logic ..... please explain what you tried, what worked and what did not work .... include the text of any error messages that might have been shown  ...... the question about the delay is also unclear

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Sant, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think doing things probabilistically is a good approach.  You have to realize that your sensors aren't perfect.  You have to contend with things like noise, false positives, false negatives, limited field of view, etc.  Changing your view of the data from binary to probabilistic will make it easier to combine.  And you should be able to find a good book on [probabilistic robotics](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/).

Answer (score 0):

That is not an easy task to do. There are SLAM methods that can optimize the time delay as well. Theory can be applied in your case but you should make your own implementation.

[This](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6942599/) paper describes the basic theory that you need.